# How to sort 1 value in array to top?

Tags: php

For Example:

```
$array = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
```

now I want to sort number 3 on top, this result:

```
$array = ("3", "1", "2", "4", "5");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort all your array except one, try this :

```
function cmpToTop($a, $b){
    if($a === '3') return -1; //Change comparison value
    if($b === '3') return 1; //Change comparison value
    if($a === $b) return 0;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array('3', '2', '5', '6', '3', '1');

cmpToTop($a, "cmp"); //Result : array('3', '3', '1', '2', '5', '6')
```

Answer (score 0):

For shifting in a circle use:

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
while($array[0] != '3')
    array_push($array, array_shift($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just store the number you want to put in the top;
move each number before it backwards one step;
Then you put the stored number in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping someone will have a better way of doing this because this seems like a bit of a workaround for something so simple but this function will work:

```
<?php
    $arrayData = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrayData); echo "</pre>";

    $arrayData = moveToTop($arrayData, 2);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrayData); echo "</pre>";


    function moveToTop($someArray, $key){
        $tmp = $someArray[$key];
        unset($someArray[$key]);
        array_unshift($someArray, $tmp);
        return array_values($someArray);
    }
?>
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $a = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");  
  foreach($a as $k => $v)
  {
    if($v == 3)
   {
    array_unshift($a,$v);
    unset($a[$k]);
   } 
  }
  print_r($a);
```

So, far with limited information about the criteria.